# Can I deploy a smart contract from studio.ethereum.org to mainnet?

Tags: contract-deployment, ethereum-studio

I found this website quite useful: [studio.ethereum.org](https://studio.ethereum.org/). However, it seems that I cannot deploy smart contracts from there to mainnet. Is this correct, or is there a way to do it?

Comment: It seems that it's not possible: https://discuss.superblocks.com/t/private-test-network/44/2